# How to pause a Slideshowify slideshow on mouseenter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshowify

I am using a jQuery plugin called [Slideshowify](http://www.subchild.com/slideshowify/). Unfortunately, it doesn't come with many options or functions, so I have been forced to attempt to create my own pause and play with mouse enter/leave.

As seen below, I have managed to stop the animating simply using `.stop()` on `mouseenter`, but I have not yet managed to find a way to play the animation from its current state after `mouseleave`. 
How can I achieve this?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-320-500-2.jpg" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-h-c-320-500-9.jpg" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-h-c-320-500-10.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#slideshow {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#slideshow img').slideshowify({
    parentEl: '#slideshow'
});

$("#slideshow").on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).find('div > img').stop(true, false);
});
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vszrbjc4/5/)**